# How to profile Django middleware itself?

Tags: python, django, profiler, django-middleware

There are many ways to profile Django views. For example [custom middleware](https://gun.io/blog/fast-as-fuck-django-part-1-using-a-profiler/) or [this custom tab](https://github.com/dmclain/django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler) for Django Debug toolbar.

What is the way to profile django middleware itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encapsulate all the other middleware. In your outermost middleware, in `process_request`, start profiling. I generally use `profile.enable()` and `profile.disable()` with a `cProfile.Profile` instance, this allows me to start and stop profiling at an arbitrary point, whereas `profile.runcall()` requires you to call an actual function, which is not the way middleware works in Django.

In your innermost middleware, define `process_view()` to simply return `HttpResponse('')`. This way, the view itself is not called and won't be included in your profile.

Then, in your outermost middleware again, define `process_response()` to stop profiling and output the profile either to the browser or to a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove everything other than the middleware from the profiling results, you could just create an empty view that returns a blank HttpResponse.

Comment: The functionality of the middleware could very well depend on which view is called or which url is accessed.